# Get an array of events throug the facebook-api

Tags: php, facebook, events, api

Still don't got it, how to use the facebook api, for things like that.

This one succeeds...

```
$userlocation = $facebook->api('/me', 'get', array("fields"=>"name,location"));
```

This one returns an empty aray...

```
$events= $facebook->api('/me/events', 'get', array("fields"=>"id, owner, name,location"));
```

thx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you didn't acquire the `user_events` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)!
[image]

Comment: how can i receive the permissions i gave.. 
the user_events permission is needed for new users, so maybe it's because of the former permissions were not including user_events.

just checked..my privacy settings.. you are right.

Comment: just add it, `<fb:login-button perms="user_events,read_stream"></fb:login-button>` and next time the user logs in he will get prompted by the scrennshot I attached