# Facebook API - really basic events.get() request, help needed

Tags: php, facebook

I want to get all the events of the logged in user, who has the app installed.

This is not intended to be a public app and is for me only. The user (me) has has given the app permissions like below:
[image]

I'm using this code:

```
<?php
// get all events for logged in fb user
require_once    'facebook.php';
$app_apikey =   'my-key-is-here';
$app_secret =   'my-secret-is-here';
$facebook =     new Facebook($app_apikey, $app_secret);
$user_id =      $facebook->require_login(); //returns my facebook user_id fine!
$events =       $facebook->api_client->events_get($user_id); //returns nothing!
echo $events;   //nothing    
print_r($events); //no array to print
print_r(json_decode($events)); //no array to print 
?>
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting a no results from `events.get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems that you are using the old php-sdk? try using this [one](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/).
2. Make sure you have the `user_events` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions). Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671470/get-an-array-of-events-throug-the-facebook-api/4671878#4671878).
3. With the new SDK, it's as simple as:

   ```
   $events= $facebook->api('/me/events');
   ```